# como puedo pasar json a html

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Hola estoy iniciando en el mundillo de vuejs
estoy consumiendo un campo detalle donde tengo código HTML:

```
<p>alhdlkfjaldkfkaldjflkasdfkladsf</p>
<p>asdfaslfdjaslñfjalñsdfjlkñasjfdklajsdfasf</p>
<p>adsfadsf</p>
```

Cómo  hago para al ejecutar el código se ejecute el HTML y no muestre la etiquetas `<p>` y las otras?

mi json es asi:

```
  "detalle": "<p>alhdlkfjaldkfkaldjflkasdfkladsf</p><p>asdfaslfdjaslñfjalñsdfjlkñasjfdklajsdfasf</p><p>adsfadsf</p>",
```

mi codigo completo

```
<div id="app" v-cloak>
```

```
  <div class="sk-double-bounce" v-if="solicitud.length === 0">
    <div class="sk-child sk-double-bounce1"></div>
    <div class="sk-child sk-double-bounce2"></div>
  </div>      

  <div class="grid-item-content" :style="{ 'background': solicitud.color }">
    <div class="text-center" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #333"><h3>Nota #{{ solicitud.id}}</h3></div>
    <div><h4>{{ solicitud.nombre }}</h4></div>
    <div><h4>{{ solicitud.celular }}</h4></div>
    <div><h5>{{ solicitud.email }}</h5></div>
    <div :id="solicitud.id">{{ solicitud.detalle }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var urlSolicitudes = "<?php echo DOMINIO ?>api/solicitudes";
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  created: function() {
    this.getSolicitudes();
  },
  data: {
    listSolicitudes: []
  },
  methods: {
    getSolicitudes: function() {
      axios.get(urlSolicitudes).then(response => {
        this.listSolicitudes = response.data
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Gracias

Comment: Hola, no me queda claro lo que deseas haces

Comment: ¿Quieres decir que en tu página aparecen visibles las etiquetas `<p>` en lugar de ser interpretadas como *párrafos*?

Comment: exacto es basicamente eso, no se interpreta como parrafos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vue.js por default interpreta todos los valores dentro de los **double mustaches** como texto plano para evitar ataques XSS. Para poder imprimir `html` necesitarás usar la directiva de Vue.js `v-html="datoAImprimir"`.

```
<div :id="solicitud.id" v-html="solicitud.detalle"></div>
```

No es recomendable imprimir `raw html` que tenga como fuente al usuario sin antes validar que no exista código malicioso.

Te recomiendo que le des un vistazo a las siguientes páginas para más información:

- https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

Comment: excelente no sabia esa directiva de Vue.js gracias

Answer (score 0):

seguro no estas accediendo bien al json... probe y si me funciona normalmente de esta manera:

Guardas tu json en una variable

```
const tujson = { "detalle": "<p>alhdlkfjaldkfkaldjflkasdfkladsf</p><p>asdfaslfdjaslñfjalñsdfjlkñasjfdklajsdfasf</p><p>adsfadsf`</p>",}
```

Luego accedes de esta manera a tus parrafos:

```
tujson.detalle;
```

Comment: este es mi codigo completo